# React Axios - Delay GET method

Tags: reactjs, axios, request, delay

I am building an application which limits the amount of GET requests to 3 per second. However I have a list that I need to loop through and make a GET request per object. How do I make this work?

I have tried putting the request in a setTimeout without success

```
const makeRequest = () => {
        arrayWithObjects.map((x: any) => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                getTaskDetail(x._id)
            }, 2000)
        })
    }
```

I have also tried with putting a timeout on the call itself

```
const getTaskDetail = (taskId: string) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        return axios.get(`/admin/task/${taskId}`);
    }, 2000)
};
```

Comment: you might solve your problem with Promise.all

Comment: @SinanYaman thank you. this resolved my problem :)

Comment: @elmgren can you elaborate on your solution?

Comment: @Biaspoint I ended up creating a delay function using a promise and calling this function every iteration.

However I would do this with a middleware today :)